# Contents of Song Books, Real Books, Sheet Music Collections

Tags: music

There are lots of sheet music in my cabinet. When looking for a certain score I'm always lost.

I want to build a list of all my sheet music in order to quickly search through this list. This list should contain searchable data including:

- song title
- author / composer
- page number
- date
- rights holder
- includes songtext, chords, ...
- musical style (as jazz, blues, classical)
- ...

and of course data about the songbook as

- title
- instruments
- ...

So I'm looking for any kind of structured data from song books, real books (jazz), collections, etc. My favority music is popular music from 1920 (starting with ragtine, blues) up to now. Main instruments are piano, trumpet, trombone.

Please note: I don't need the paper sheets since I already got them in printed form.

Comment: Found some jazz collections here: https://github.com/aspiers/book-indices
Unfortunately there is just the title and the page number included.

Comment: Have you tried to extract the data from Worldcat? Here is an [example](https://www.worldcat.org/title/real-book/oclc/56846058&referer=brief_results) for the data of the real book plus all included songs. Unfortunately without page numer or artist.

Comment: Maybe the [Sheet Music Consortium database](http://digital2.library.ucla.edu/sheetmusic/).

Comment: Thanks, but I only see user interfaces, no api or open data sets with extended information about the sheet music pieces :-(

And screen scraping from sites is no option for me at the moment.